# Free folder syncing software that can run as process or service

Tags: windows-xp, directory, synchronization

I was wondering if there was a folder syncing software out there that would sync a network (smb) folder to a local folder. There are a few that i have googled:

1. Puresync
2. Allway Sync
   ...

To name a few. 
But the catch is the syncing process stops as soon as the user logs off! 
I need something that would keep on running as a process without any user login!
thanks
Cheers

Comment: This is a question for superuser.

Answer (score 1):

[Get Dropbox](http://db.tt/uGfDpvY) i think its the best for sync.